# How can I obtain the word context for a list of search terms in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp

I just set up my first elasticsearch cluster and uploaded a few thousand documents. Now I would like to perform a relatively simple task: I have a list of search terms and, for each term, would like to obtain a list of the documents in my database that contain this search term together with the word context (5 words before search term, 5 words after search term).

Is there a simple way to do this? I already searched a lot but have not found a satisfying answer.

**Example**

- I have a database with one document (id: 1): "The dog runs up the
  hill to fly a yellow kite. He looks happy."
- I have one search term: "hill".
- I would like to write a request that returns the id 1 together with
  the 5 words before ("The dog runs up the") and the 5 words after ("to
  fly a yellow kite.") the search term ("hill").

Comment: You should probably provide a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I added a short example. I hope it helps or is it still unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to make elasticsearch return *exactly* n words around a match, but you can use the highlighting feature to retrieve the rough context and then post-process the result in your application.

By default, elasticsearch tries to determine what context makes a good snippet, so you maybe have to increase the size of this window by setting `fragment_size` (number of characters of the returned snippet).

Here is an example query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "yourtextfield": "hill"
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "yourtextfield": {}
        },
        "boundary_scanner": "word",
        "type": "plain",
        "fragment_size": 150,
        "pre_tags": "",
        "post_tags": ""
    }
}
```

Normally, the match is encapsulated in `<em>` and `</em>`, but you can modify or remove them with via `pre_tags` and `post_tags`. It might be useful to utilize them as markers so that you know what word exactly matched your query.

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) as well, there are many good examples that might help you.